# create a user and set up key based ssh on his own account

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, ssh

I am trying learn hadoop so I am following a tutorial but I have a problem with the installation of hadoop.

I should create a new user and set up a ssh key (using ubuntu) with this.

```
su
adduser
passwd
su - hadoop
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

when I enter the last command O get

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

don't have any idea what to write there just pressed enter and I got

```
Could not create directory '/home/hadoop/.ssh': No such file or directory
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
open /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa failed: No such file or directory.
Saving the key failed: /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.
```

can someone help please.

Comment: not a programming question; try super user or unix & linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the requested directory before writing the file into it:

```
mkdir -p /home/hadoop/.ssh/
chmod 700 /home/hadoop/.ssh/
```

And also change the permission so it is not too open for private data.

Comment: thank you for your answer it worked for me know i have the new user and i generated a ssh key and i tried to connect with ssh localhost put it ask for a password,     hadoop@localhost's password: i didn't put any password?

Comment: I have no idea which tutorial you followed and where is the mistake from this chunk of information in this question. But sorting things a bit out and formulating another question (rather on SuperUser) is probably best way to go.

Comment: ok thank you a lot @Jakuje